# Chosen JavaScript can't click/select on update dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I have a website where I need to filter a list of media types depending on the media family. ie: if `print` is chosen, it must only show options to do with print, if `digital` is chosen, it must only show options to do with digital stuff.

I can update the list with new values, but then they are not clickable anymore?

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am already using: `$("#mec_id").trigger("liszt:updated");` where `mec_id` is the id of the select. Here is the HTML after the `media family` is chosen, when trying to click on the `media type` it does not give the option to click/select the option. In the code I have selected `print` because there is only one value for the dropdown there (to save space in the code).

HTML:

```
<select id="mec_id" class=" chosen-select" tabindex="-1" multiple="" style="width: 100%; display: none;" data-placeholder="Select Media Type" name="mec_id[]">
    <option data-val="12" value="print">print</option>
</select>
<div id="mec_id_chosen" class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 349px;" title="">
    <ul class="chosen-choices">
        <li class="search-field">
            <input class="default" type="text" style="width: 132px;" autocomplete="off"   value="Select Media Type" tabindex="8">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="chosen-drop">
        <ul class="chosen-results">
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="12">print</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript/JQuery (function of the AJAX Success call):

```
   success: function (data) {
                var ul = document.createElement('ul');
                ul.className = "chosen-results";
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        $('#media_types .chosen-drop').contents().remove();
                        $('#mec_id').contents().remove();
                    }
                    var text = data[i].text;
                    var li = document.createElement('li');
                    li.className = "active-result";
                    li.setAttribute('data-option-array-index', data[i].id);
                    li.innerHTML = text;
                    ul.appendChild(li);
                    // create options
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.setAttribute('data-val', data[i].id);
                    option.value = data[i].text;
                    option.text = data[i].text;
                    document.getElementById("mec_id").appendChild(option);
                }
                $('#mec_id_chosen .chosen-drop').append(ul);
                $("#mec_id").trigger("liszt:updated");
            },
```

Comment: What plugin are you using for the select input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's not suppose to be `chosen:updated` instead of `liszt:updated`

I don't see any references to liszt - http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/